# How do a load a table that has a column that has more than 10000 characters?

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I have an Excel file that the users can free text one column.  In this case the users have some cases where they have over 10000 characters.  I have seen from the message boards that the nvarchar(max) should work.  I created a table that is just the column name and then set the field equal to nvarchar and I am still getting an error.
This is the code that I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Sample_Table(
    [CC_Comments] nvarchar(max)NULL
) 
GO
```

And I am getting the following error messages:

> Executing (Error)
>   Messages
>   Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column " CC Comments " returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - Scrap_txt.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[ CC Comments ]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Source - Scrap_txt.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[ CC Comments ]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:\Users\e4h7x8r\Desktop\Scrap.txt" on data row 772.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - Scrap_txt returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post how you are importing it and some sample data--like what's on row 722 of that sheet? Looks like you may not have a LF or CR that would break the rows up and thus it's trying to cram the entire sheet into an single row. Or, there could be a ton of data on row 722

Comment: I am using the import wizard right now to try and import the data.  The data that is on row 722 is a combination of text and dates.  For example: 9/22/17 - Spoke with patient x.  10-31-17 Spoke with Patient about current health situation.  The user is using a combination of '-' s and '/', not sure if that is an issue or not.

Comment: I found a way to make this work.  I added a column called Len and then calculated the length in the column using the LEN function in Excel.  I then sorted it descending order and then loaded the file and changed the the type to text_stream which is working.  I needed something easy like this since I am only loading this file once a month.